# std::tuple get() member function

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, tuples

`boost::tuple` has a `get()` member function used like this:

```
tuple<int, string, string> t(5, "foo", "bar");
cout << t.get<1>();  // outputs "foo"
```

It seems the C++0x `std::tuple` does not have this member function, and you have to instead use the non-member function form:

```
std::get<1>(t);
```

which to me looks uglier.

Is there any particular reason why `std::tuple` doesn't have the member function? Or is it just my implementation (GCC 4.4)?

Comment: As a design rule of thumb, non-member functions are to be preferred anyway.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

From C++0x draft:

> [ Note: The reason get is a nonmember function is that if this functionality had been provided as a member function, code where the type depended on a template parameter would have required using the template keyword. — end note ]

This can be illustrated with this code:

```
template <typename T>
struct test
{
  T value;
  template <int ignored>
  T&  member_get ()
  {  return value;  }
};

template <int ignored, typename T>
T&  free_get (test <T>& x)
{  return x.value;  }

template <typename T>
void
bar ()
{
  test <T>  x;
  x.template member_get <0> ();  // template is required here
  free_get <0> (x);
};
```

Comment: I see. Still, they could have provided both member and non-member functions like boost, if for no other reason that to be compatible with boost (since a lot of people are likely to have already been using boost tuples before switching to C++0x).

Comment: @HighCommander4 Whereas I understand your argument, boost compatibility alone is not a sufficient reason *on its own*, since compatibility to existing solutions shouldn't be *the only* driving force for providing something in a *new* standard and even boost is not the non-plus-ultra and may profit from some revision. Those general words being said, I still agree that member-`get`s would have been a good idea.

Comment: Now that we have C++11 that no longer requiring template keyword, we can totally have a member function now? Just a proposal needed?

Answer (score 34):

The existing answers are great and certainly for the standards committee were vital for this purpose. But there is another issue that I think is important enough to mention.

With free functions, you have the ability to modify an interface *without* changing the definition of a class. You can make any type "gettable" simply by specializing the global `get`. With a member function, you would have to directly modify the class.

Range-based `for` looks for member `begin/end` on class types, but it also looks for non-member `begin/end` via ADL. These APIs can be used with any container, even those that don't have `begin/end` functions. You can specialize it for, for example, LibXML2 element types, such that you can range-based `for` over `xmlElement*`'s.

You can't do that if they had to be member functions.

In C++, free functions are a natural interface for many operations that could be done on many different kinds of classes.

Comment: `std::begin/std::end` are also good examples of how member and non-member functions can work together nicely. You can use either with most containers.

Comment: Ok this is cool and all but *provide the member function too!!*

Answer (score 15):

N3090/3092, §20.4.2.6/8: "Note: The reason get is a nonmember function is that if this functionality had been provided as a member function, code where the type depended on a template parameter would have required using the template keyword. —end note"