# Why is std::get not a member function of std::tuple et al.?

Tags: c++, c++11, getter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [std::tuple get() member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313479/stdtuple-get-member-function)

There seem to be separate overloads for `std::get`, for different homogeneous and heterogeneous containers such as for [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get).

This seems a bit awkward; The more obvious choice would be if there was an `std::tuple::get()` with one template parameter (the index). I'd be surprised if this choice was made on a whim, so I wonder why the standardisation committee would choose to make it a free function instead of a member function, despite the latter being a more natural interface.

Is there any good reason?

Comment: @JesseGood: Darn, I searched the heck out of this. I agree, it's a dupe.

Comment: It should also be noted that, with free functions, you can provide overloads *without* changing the definition of a class. You can make any type superficially act like a `tuple` simply by overloading the global `get`, even classes that you're not allowed to change. In C++, free functions *are* a natural interface; C++ isn't Java and C#, where everything must be a member of something.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I don't dispute that. I just think that in *this* case, a member function would have been a *more* natural interface. But that might be just taste.

Comment: Then you won't be able to make third-party class that you can't change to behave as a `std::tuple`.

Comment: @jons34yp: Sure I can. I can just implement `MyTuple::get` to work just like `std::tuple::get` -- if such a thing would exist. This is even better, because I don't have to go violating the `std` namespace by implementing my stuff in there.

Comment: Let's say you want tuple-like interface to std::string (or similar interface that you can't possibly get patched upstream). What's then?

Comment: @jons34yp: Then, you're doing it wrong. I'm having trouble imagining any scenario where changing the `std` semantics would not break your neck.