# Why is std::get<T> for `variant` a global function?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, c++17

Can anyone tell me why `std::get<T>` of C++17 is a global function and not a member-function of `variant<...>`?

Comment: I'll ask the complementary question: why should it be a member function?

Comment: [Same as for tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313479/stdtuple-get-member-function) most certainly. The syntax gets too ugly.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Discoverability, intuition, consistency with other containers.

Answer (score 9):

If `get<T>()` were a member function template, a `template` keyword would be needed when it is called in a dependent context. For example:

```
template <typename Variant>
void f(Variant const& v) {
    auto x0 = v.template get<T>(); // if it were a member
    auto x1 = get<T>(v);           // using a non-member function
}
```

Even without a `using` declaration or directive `get()` is found as both `std::variant<...>` and `get()` are declared in namespace `std`. Thus, there seems to be no good reason to make it a member function as the global function is easier to use.

Comment: Well, you need a function template named `get` in scope for `get<T>(v)` to be parsed correctly. Still, better than having to write `template` at every turn.

Comment: @T.C.: good point - with the template parameter it isn't directly found via ADL. That may argue for an uncallable function template being declared at global scope (e.g., `template <typename T> typename T::uncallable get();`; the number of arguments don't really matter...).

Comment: Why is `emplace()` a member then? That doesn't seem to need the `template` keyword: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/emplace

Comment: @ShdNx: the problem is with parsing member  function templates with explicitly specified template arguments: while `get<T>(v)` inherently requires that `T` gets specified, `v.emplace(a...)` desuces all its template parameters. Hence, the problem doesn’t exist over there.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: actually, you need to explicitly specify `T` for `emplace`, otherwise it doesn't know what to try to construct from the arguments given. See my earlier link to cppreference.com for examples.

Comment: @ShdNx: interesting - I didn’t realize that `std::variant::emplace` also takes an explicit template argument. Of course, that means that you’ll need to write `v.template emplace<T>(a...)` in contexts where `v`’s type is a template parameter. The implication is that the designers of `std::variant` assumed that `emplace` is normally used on objects with a non-dependent name.