# How to make set<T>(args...) method?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

For example, I have a class

```
class A
{
public:
    template<class T, class... Args>
    void set(Args&&... args);

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Member1Type> m_member1;
    std::shared_ptr<Member2Type> m_member2; // Member types are all different.
};
```

And I hope I can use it as

```
A a;
a.set<Member1Type>(args... to construct Member1Type);
```

which like

```
make_shared<T>(args...);
```

My question is how to link member type to the correct member in implementing the method. Thanks!

Comment: You could provide a [pointer to data member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members) to `set` to tell it which member to set. But to do that you would need to expose the members, including their underlying type at which point there isn't really any point in trying to encapsulate it with a setter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd populate a `std::tuple<MemberType1*, MemberType2*, ...>` in the ctor, so you can then use `get<T*>(m_tuple)` in `A::set<T, Args...>`

[edit] 
Or as StoryTeller suggested, without extra members:

```
private:
    std::tuple <
        std::shared_ptr<Member1Type>,
        std::shared_ptr<Member2Type>
    > m_members;
```

You'd now need `std::get<std::shared_ptr<T>>(m_members)`

Comment: Note that this only works if each member has a different type and invalidates the compiler generated constructors and assignment operators. They would copy or assign the `tuple` which would point to the referenced instance's members instead of the assigned or constructed instance's.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Ah, I see what you're getting at. My logic was that `m_member1` might be an empty shared_ptr so I couldn't use references. But you can do away with the individual members, and store the shared_ptr directly in the tuple.

Comment: @MSalters If the raw pointer's lifetime is coupled to an existing `shared_ptr` then there is no reason to share ownership.Raw pointers are perfectly fine when they aren't owning. Edit : Though you may want a tuple that points to the `shared_ptr<T>*` instead to allow you to assign to it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: The uniqueness is implied by the need to select the member by the single argument `T` of `set<T, Args...>`.

Comment: I found tuple has no such get() member method. what I need turns to finding the index of the type and then call std::get<i>(m_members) method, right? Thanks!

Comment: @user1899020: My bad, [it changed to a non-member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313479/stdtuple-get-member-function) when it was added to the Standard. No need for an index.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to go the `tuple` approach, one way you could do this is to provide private getters for each member, overloaded on a tag type:

```
template <typename T> struct type_t { };
template <typename T> constexpr type_t<T> type{};

class A
{
public:
    template<class T, class... Args>
    void set(Args&&... args) {
        get(type<T>) = std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    auto& get(type_t<Member1Type>) { return m_member1; }
    auto& get(type_t<Member2Type>) { return m_member2; }

    std::shared_ptr<Member1Type> m_member1;
    std::shared_ptr<Member2Type> m_member2;
};
```

The `auto&` return avoids the need to write the type again, which already appears in the parameter list (kind of the same way you wouldn't repeat the type when writing a C++ cast).

Comment: I am wandering what the 2nd line is? A global variable?

Comment: @user1899020 A [variable template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template).

Answer (score -1):

[enter link description here][۱

**

**strong

**

[1](http://Yahoo.com): http://www.google play.com

> `enter code here`quote

1. [List item][۱]