# Why cpp design its api like std::get<T>( some_tuple ) instead of some_tuple.get<T>?

Tags: c++

Also same question for variant, array.

A related question answerd why it use compile-time parameter, but not why not design its api as a member function.([Why are C++ tuples so weird?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56937839/why-are-c-tuples-so-weird))

`tuple.get<int>()` looks more semantic than `std::get<int>( some_tuple )`

Comment: "looks more semantic" what does that mean?

Comment: `std::get` can be used on any tuple-like type in the standard library, like `std::array`, `std::pair`, `std::variant`.

Comment: not everything must be a member. Every thing that can be a non-member makes the types more simple and easier to use. What would be the benefit of making it a member of many different types rather than 1 template that works for all types?

Comment: your only argument is that a member function would be "better", but they are not, actually the common recommendation in C++ says something else. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21028902/4117728 and https://isocpp.org/blog/2018/02/free-your-functions-klaus-iglberger and else where...

Comment: To me, a good reason to prefer member functions to free functions is that IDE can much better autocomplete member functions, as the context is known.